# Custom assertion on Gatling

Tags: scala, gatling, scala-gatling

Is it possible to create a custom assert based on a boolean value?
Something like this:

```
setUp(scn.inject(rampUsers(7) over (1 minutes))).protocols(httpProtocol).
assertions(
  assert(/*method that returns boolean value*/),
 /*other assertions*/
)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Gatling has a concept of checks. This allows you to verify if the response contained certain elements or not.

https://gatling.io/docs/2.3/http/http_check/

Comment: Thanks!, yes I do know about checks, but the reason of the question is because I am gathering the soap responses while executing and storing them inside a collection, and at the end I need to verify that the collection is ordered, so I have to call a method do that validation and returns a boolean value.

Comment: That's not the purpose of a load test. The scenario which you described above is a functional test. not a load test.

Comment: I do not agree with @KnowsNotMuch, you could validate the output of X requests because you've found a performance issue which is raised after some % of load test.

Answer (score 0):

We had the same requirement, do one final check/assert at the end of the simulation.

Our setUp(...) is called inside a Scala Class that can have *before* and/or *after* block.

We end up with something like this inside the Scala Class.

```
after {
  assert(<my custom check>, "My custom check failed.")
}
```

Hope that helps.